# Pygame - math vector. Reporting discrepancies between declared parameters and actual arguments

Tags: python, pygame

Hi everyone I am new to python so I started following YouTubers to create games. I have attached my code below and imported `Vector2` from PyGame. but the problem is on *line 16* `self.pos = Vector2(width/2,height/2)` onwards. Pycharm is prompting me to that the arguments are wrong.

When I run my program this error appears.

> ```
> self.pos += self.vel + ( 0.5*self.acc.x ) #d = v +0.5` a formula to calculate dist
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'.

Please help thank you.

import  pygame as pg
from  settings import  *
from pygame.math import Vector2

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

```
def __init__(self):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pg.Surface((30,40)) #simple sprite
    self.image.fill(yellow) #color of sprite
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (width/2,height/2) #centre the sprite
    self.pos = Vector2(width/2, height/2)  #position vector
    self.vel = Vector2(0,0) #velocity vector
    self.acc = Vector2 (0, 0)  #accelaration vector

def update(self):
    self.acc = (0,0)
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed() #if pressed
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x = -0.5  #accelarate left
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x = 0.5  #accelarate right

    self.vel += self.acc #velocity adds to acceleration
    self.pos += self.vel + ( 0.5*self.acc.x ) #d = v +0.5a  formula to calculate dist

    self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Comment: Hi, Habib, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: In line 12 you define `acc` to be *tuple* `(0, 0)`. I assume `keys[pg.K_LEFT]` and `keys[pg.K_RIGHT]` are both "falsy" (evaluated to `False` in lines 14 and 16, respectively, because if they weren't you would get an error in line 15 or 16 as `self.acc` does not have the attribute `x`. (Tuples do not have attributes, *classes* do.) Depending on what you're trying to achieve, defining `self.acc`as a list using `self.acc = [0, 0]` and replacing all occurences of `self.acc.x` with `self.acc[0]` may bring you one step further.

Comment: Perhaps you would benefit from reading on Python data types a bit (and find out why a list is required here instead of a tuple...)

Comment: I have not yet fiddled with Pygame so this is just an idea: Does the `Vector2` class have an attribute `x`? If so, try to change `self.acc = (0, 0)` to `self.acc = Vector2(0, 0)`.

Comment: Hi applesoup thank you for the warm welcome. Yes the problem was solved when I changed the self.acc = Vector2(0,0). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor the attribute `self.acc` is initialized by a [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html). At this point `self.acc.x` is valid, because the object of `Vector2` has an attribute `x`:

> ```
>  def __init__(self):
>
>      # [...]
>
>      self.acc = Vector2 (0, 0)  #accelaration vector
> ```

But in the method `update` a tuple is assigned to the attribute `self.acc`:

> ```
> def update(self):
>     self.acc = (0,0)
> ```

This causes the error

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'.

when you try to access `self.acc.x`, because the tuple has not attribute `x`, of course:

Replace the line `self.acc = (0,0)` by `self.acc = Vector2(0, 0)` to solve the issue:

```py
def update(self):

    self.acc = Vector2(0, 0)

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed() #if pressed
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x = -0.5  #accelarate left
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x = 0.5  #accelarate right

    self.vel += self.acc #velocity adds to acceleration
    self.pos += self.vel + ( 0.5*self.acc.x ) #d = v +0.5a  formula to calculate dist

    self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Comment: Hi Rabbid76, Thank you for the detailed description. Yes the probem was solved when i changed it to Vector2! Once again i really appreciate the help!